# fixed footer for print not taking full page width

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a hidden footer which is shown when printing a page, but when i try to print on chrome it's not taking the full width page. why?

The code i am using

```css
<style type="text/css">
   @media screen {
        div.divhead {
            display: none;
        }

        div.divFooter {
            display: none;
        }

    }
    @media print {
        div.divFooter {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div>
   <div>
      <div class="divhead">
         <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/head.jpg" Width="100%" runat="server" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="divFooter">
      <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="~/Images/footer.jpg" Width="100%" runat="server" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a width when using position fixed and absolute.

Add `width: 100%` to `div.divFooter {}`.

Comment: i still have the issue

Comment: in my case I had to add -ve left and right. So I added left -45px right: -45px (based on my page margin settings). And I did not had to set the whole page margin or padding to 0

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this CSS

```
body, html{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

 @media print {
        div.divFooter {
            position: absolute;
            min-width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i still have the issue

Comment: try using ``position: absolute``, I updated the answer as well.

Comment: it takes the full width but the footer moved to the top of page

Comment: do you still have it set to ``bottom: 0``?